# Hiding an SVG at default until you click the button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

How do I make sure that the left Arrow (SVG) is hidden at default.

The arrows cycles through the array, when it has reached `Wheels` the right arrow disappears, when you are back at `Door` the left arrow disappears.
The arrows reappear and disappear continuously so that you know when you you're the last index or the first index.

How can I make the left arrow disappear at the start when opening the page, instead of having to first press the right arrow and then the left arrow.

```js
var parts = ["Door", "Window", "Engine", "Wheels"];
var count = 0
$("#parts").html(parts[0]);

$("#rightb").click(function() {
  count = (count + 1)
  $("#parts").html(parts[count])
  if (count >= 3) {
    $("#rightb").hide();
    $("#leftb").click(function() {
      $("#rightb").show()
    })
  }
});

$("#leftb").click(function() {
  count = (count - +1)
  $("#parts").html(parts[count])
  if (count == 0) {
    $("#leftb").css("display", "none")
    $("#rightb").click(function() {
      $("#leftb").css("display", "block")
    })
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

.arrow {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
}

#leftb {
  position: absolute;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: -200px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 60px;
  filter: drop-shadow( 2px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7));
}

#rightb {
  position: absolute;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: -200px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 60px;
  filter: drop-shadow( 2px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7));
}

#parts {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: 'MS Reference Sans Serif', sans-serif;
  text-shadow: 10px 10px 30px black;
  color: White;
  margin-top: 35px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  place-content: middle;
}


/* Arrow Animations */

.arrow {
  transform: translateX(-0%) translateY(-0%);
  transition: transform 0.1s;
}

.arrow-top,
.arrow-bottom {
  background-color: #666;
  height: 4px;
  left: -5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
}

.arrow-top:after,
.arrow-bottom:after {
  background-color: #fff;
  top: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.arrow-top {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform-origin: bottom right;
}

.arrow-top:after {
  left: 100%;
  right: 0;
  transition-delay: 0.5s;
}

.arrow-bottom {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform-origin: top right;
}

.arrow-bottom:after {
  left: 0;
  right: 100%;
  transition-delay: 0.5s;
}

.arrow:hover .arrow-top:after {
  left: 0;
  transition-delay: 0.5s;
}

.arrow:hover .arrow-bottom:after {
  right: 0;
  transition-delay: 0.5s;
}

.arrow:active {
  transform: translateX(-0%) translateY(-0%) scale(0.9);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="arrow">


  <button class="arrow left" id="leftb">

                <svg width="20px" height="40px" viewBox="0 0 50 80" xml:space="preserve">
                <polyline fill="none" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="4" 
    http://jsfiddle.net/JulianDotExe/mrsvL35w/33/#            stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" 
                points="45.63,75.8 0.375,38.087 45.63,0.375 "/></svg>

                </button>


  <div id="parts">Parts</div>


  <button class="arrow right" id="rightb">

                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
                width="20px" height="40px" viewBox="0 0 50 80" xml:space="preserve">
                <polyline fill="none" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="4" 
                stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" 
                points="0.375,0.375 45.63,38.087 0.375,75.8 "/></svg>
                
                </button>
```

Comment: Give the left button a default style of `display: none;`?

Comment: Add `display: none` to it in your css...? https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/aju19bdn/

Comment: It shouldn't stay hidden, I edited the question, the arrows reappear and disappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can initially give the left button a default style of `display: none` as @Reyno suggested and give it `display: block` on button press.

```js
var parts = ["Door", "Window", "Engine", "Wheels"];
var count = 0
$("#parts").html(parts[0]);


$("#rightb").click(function() {
  count = (count + 1)
  $("#leftb").css("display", "block")
  $("#parts").html(parts[count])
  if (count >= 3) {
    $("#rightb").hide();
    $("#leftb").click(function() {
      $("#rightb").show()
    })
  }
});

$("#leftb").click(function() {
  count = (count - +1)
  $("#parts").html(parts[count])
  if (count == 0) {
    $("#leftb").css("display", "none")
    $("#rightb").click(function() {
      $("#leftb").css("display", "block")
    })
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

.arrow {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
}

#leftb {
  position: absolute;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
  margin-left: -200px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 60px;
  filter: drop-shadow( 2px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7));
}

#rightb {
  position: absolute;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: -200px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 60px;
  filter: drop-shadow( 2px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7));
}

#parts {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: 'MS Reference Sans Serif', sans-serif;
  text-shadow: 10px 10px 30px black;
  color: White;
  margin-top: 35px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  place-content: middle;
}


/* Arrow Animations */

.arrow {
  transform: translateX(-0%) translateY(-0%);
  transition: transform 0.1s;
}

.arrow-top,
.arrow-bottom {
  background-color: #666;
  height: 4px;
  left: -5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
}

.arrow-top:after,
.arrow-bottom:after {
  background-color: #fff;
  top: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.arrow-top {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform-origin: bottom right;
}

.arrow-top:after {
  left: 100%;
  right: 0;
  transition-delay: 0.5s;
}

.arrow-bottom {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform-origin: top right;
}

.arrow-bottom:after {
  left: 0;
  right: 100%;
  transition-delay: 0.5s;
}

.arrow:hover .arrow-top:after {
  left: 0;
  transition-delay: 0.5s;
}

.arrow:hover .arrow-bottom:after {
  right: 0;
  transition-delay: 0.5s;
}

.arrow:active {
  transform: translateX(-0%) translateY(-0%) scale(0.9);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="arrow">


  <button class="arrow left" id="leftb">

                <svg width="20px" height="40px" viewBox="0 0 50 80" xml:space="preserve">
                <polyline fill="none" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="4" 
    http://jsfiddle.net/JulianDotExe/mrsvL35w/33/#            stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" 
                points="45.63,75.8 0.375,38.087 45.63,0.375 "/></svg>

                </button>


  <div id="parts">Parts</div>


  <button class="arrow right" id="rightb">

                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
                width="20px" height="40px" viewBox="0 0 50 80" xml:space="preserve">
                <polyline fill="none" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="4" 
                stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" 
                points="0.375,0.375 45.63,38.087 0.375,75.8 "/></svg>
                
                </button>
```